# Adding text to the inserted image in tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

I would like to create a figure as shown on the left side. However, as i am a beginner in latex so i changed my plan and i want to create the one as shown in the middle. It shows 7 matlab figure, with one in the top and other 6 in two rows (having three figures in each row). I also managed to add text on x-axis, y-axis and on top of all these six figures. However, all my figures are not in an accurate position and I also want to add few circles on pink and blue branches with text written alongside like A1, A2, A3. So that I could show the link between main figure and the other 6 figures. Can anyone please suggest me something. Or if anyone could guide me how to draw the one on the right side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
 

\begin{document}

\def\afig#1#2{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
 %\vspace{-5cm}
    \node [
    above right,
    inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\hspace*{-4mm}\includegraphics[width=5cm]{#1}};
    \begin{scope}[
    x={($0.1*(image.south east)$)},
    y={($0.1*(image.north west)$)}]
 \node[below of=image, node distance=2.5cm, xshift=0.1cm, yshift=0.8cm,font=\color{black}] {$i$};   

    \node at (0.5,5.3) {$\Theta_i$};
 \node[above of=image, node distance=2.2 cm, anchor=center,yshift=-9.5mm,font=\color{black}] {#2};
    \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
}
\def\Figs#1{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [
    above right,
    inner sep=0] (image) at (-1,0) {\hspace*{-4mm}\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{#1}};
    \begin{scope}[
    x={($0.1*(image.south east)$)},
    y={($0.1*(image.north west)$)}]
     \node[below of=image, node distance=2.5cm, xshift=0.1cm, yshift=0.6cm,font=\color{black}] {$i$};
  \node[left of=image, node distance=2.2 cm, anchor=center,xshift=-0.4cm, yshift=0.2 cm,font=\color{black}] {$\Theta_i$};
    \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
& 
\Figs{Figs_Trial/mainfig.pdf}{} & \\[-1mm]
\afig{Figs_Trial/K15_S.pdf}{$K=15, \lambda_{max}=17.38$} & 
\afig{Figs_Trial/K5_S.pdf}{$K=5, \lambda_{max}=17.38$} & 
\afig{Figs_Trial/K1_S.pdf} {$K=1, \lambda_{max}=17.38$}\\[-1mm]
\afig{Figs_Trial/K15_U.pdf}{$K=15, \lambda_{max}=17.38$} & 
\afig{Figs_Trial/K5_U.pdf}{$K=5, \lambda_{max}=17.38$} & 
\afig{Figs_Trial/K1_U.pdf}{$K=1, \lambda_{max}=17.38$} \\[-1mm]
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

 
\end{document}
```

[image]